QGIS Desktop Docker Image for Windows Host?
I am trying to get QGIS desktop (with GUI) running in a docker container. So far I have tried the official images on dockerhub and Github, plus all three here: https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/DockerImages.
The only image which does not immediately stop is that from elpaso, however the GUI does not seem to be available in the browser despite opening a port. According to the comments on the above link, this image uses something called Xhost, but if I understand correctly that has something to do with access to the graphics for a linux host machine - I am using a windows 11 machine.
Does anyone know of an image available for docker on windows 11 or have a suggestion for why the GUI is not talking to localhost?

The container GUI isn't accessed via a browser. You need "X Server" software for Windows. Like Cygwin X Server, XMing, or vcxsrv.  Think of it like Remote Desktop (RDP) - the remote device (in this case the docker container) accepts mouse and keyboard input and outputs the graphics, and the RDP client (in this case the X Server) draws the graphics and forwards the mouse and keyboard. I can't actually help further as I don't use docker on windows.

Is this specific for QGIS or GUIs in docker generally? (I have rstudio and open office both running in Docker but I didnt build the images so I dont know if they have some how built this in).

Linux app GUIs in Docker in general. Looks like libreoffice is a special case and uses some sort of web based VNC (a type of remote desktop protocol) wizardry.

I remain confused as to how LibreOffice manages to be available through localhost, without VcXsrv. That would have been preferable because VcXsrv does require more firewall access than I would like. However, I do have a GUI of QGIS running in a docker container and that solves my problem:
docker file:

    # Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    gnupg \
    wget \
    qgis \
    qgis-plugin-grass \
    python3-qgis \
    python3-pip \
    python3-qgis-common \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libxrender1 \
    libxtst6 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libfreetype6 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    x11-apps \
    && apt-get clean

# Set environment variable to use the host's display
ENV DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0

# Run QGIS GUI
CMD ["qgis"]

Then build it with "docker build -t qgis-gui ."
Run with "docker run -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 --rm -it qgis-gui"
